# Sin/Cos not working in java/android

Tags: java, android

Say i have

```
Log.e("deg: "+dd,  "X:"+ Math.sin( Math.toRadians(dd) ) +"| Y:"+Math.cos( Math.toRadians(dd) ) );
```

if dd = 180, then sin should be 0 and cos -1 , right? but it outpusts

deg: 180     X:1.2246467991473532E-16|      Y:-1.0

any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: int, but I think i also tried it with double and float.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value `1.2246467991473532E-16` *is* effectively zero, to 16 decimal places; it's `0.00000000000000012246`.

You just need to format the number for display, if that's the problem.

Comment: You could use, for example, the class [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Comment: got it! 
    private double format(double value) {
            return (double)Math.round(value * 1000000) / 1000000; //you can change this to round up the value(for two position use 100...)
        }

Comment: Well, or just `new DecimalFormat("#.###").format(value)`, to format with three decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above it is not an error, just the aproximation of computer's floating point arithmetic.

To get the expected answer, as sin() & cos() are between -1, 0 , +1, try to add 1 round it to the accurancy needed and substract 1.

```
x = round15(Math.sin(toRad(angle))+1)-1;
```

where round15 is defined

```
public double round15(double x){
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("0.##############E0");
    String str = twoDForm.format(x);
    return Double.valueOf(str);
}
```

It works for me, hope future readers like it.